# showViewController has long delay

Tags: ios, segue, uistoryboard

I am using the following code to create a segue between two view controllers:

```
NSString * storyboardName = @"Main";
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:storyboardName bundle: nil];
UIViewController * vc = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"SecondPage"];
[self showViewController:vc sender:self];
```

the issue I'm having is that there's a long delay before the view is shown.
I don't have anything happening in `viewDidLoad` or `viewWillAppear`, what could be causing the delay?

Comment: Where is this code? Show a bit more context.

Comment: when is that code triggered? probably on some thread other than the main thread!?

Comment: It's called in the main thread. There's a click handler for a button, when it's clicked I call this code and then there's a 5 - 10 second delay before the second view controller is shown.

The next time the button is clicked it happens instantly.